# Jmeter Validating JSON response with multiple value

Tags: json, api, validation, jmeter, response

Hi can everyone help me how to validate this response. Example I have this response and I want to validate all/selected currency value may I know how to simulate this? Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Response:

{
"uid": "123-321",
"period": "25_minutes",
"level": "symbol",
"rank_by": "volume",
"values": [
1.3211,
1.2212
],
"num_instruments": 20,
"currency": [
"USDT",
"SGD"
],
"asset_classes": [
"All"
],
"version": "1.0.0",
"measurements": [
0.42,
0.15
],
"timestamp": "2022-05-30T03:53:09"
}

I tried to use this method however its not working, 1st use this JSON Path expression "$..currency[?(@ == "USDT" || @ == "SGD")] "

Screenshot:

[image]

I used JSON Assertion

[image]

**Text response:**

Assertion failure message:Value expected to match regexp '["USDT","SGD"]', but it did not match: '["USDT","SGD"]'

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve you either need to either untick the `Match as regular expression` box

[image]

or to escape the [meta characters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) with backslashes:

[image]

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps)